# Questions on filtering out predicted boxes during training for YOLO family of algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

1. Does any of the YOLO models use NMS *during training*? From going through the papers they only explicitly state that NMS is only applied during inference, unlike Faster-RCNN.
2. Does any YOLO (or other computer vision) algorithms filter out low confidence boxes *during training* based on some threshold before computing the loss? Are there plus / minuses for doing so?